# ACPI Errors when booting , Can't boot

Tags: boot, kernel, hard-drive, bios, acpi

I recently installed ubuntu gnome 16.04 LTS in My HP-15AC122TU laptop.

I have been using this for a while.
 I wanted to genarate an xorg.conf file since having a screen-tearing whenever I play movies or scroll on pages( tried HW accelaration but didnt work). I don't remember exact things I did but I ended up breaking the xserver. I somehow fixed it. I started getting these messages when I booted up.

I am typing them coz I dont know how to genarate that O/P.

```
ACPI: watchdog: Device creation failed -16
starting version 232
ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 Serr 0x4000000 action 0xe fro
ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
ata2: SError: { DevExch }
/dev/sda3/: clean, 253461/6406144 files/25601330 blocks
ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
irq: Invalid fwnode type (2) for irqdomain
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PC10.LPCB.H_EC.ECWT] Namespace lookup failure,
ACPI Error: Methode parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN00._ON] (Mode f
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PC10.LPCB.H_EC.ECWT] Namespace lookup failure,
ACPI Error: Methode parse/execution failed [\_TZ.FN00._ON] (Mode f
acpi PNP0C0b:00: Failed to set initial power state
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PC10.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD] Namespace lookup failure,
ACPI Error: Methode parse/execution failed [\_TZ.TZ00._TMP] (Mode 
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PC10.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD] Namespace lookup failure,
ACPI Error: Methode parse/execution failed [\_TZ.TZ00._TMP] (Mode
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PC10.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD] Namespace lookup failure,
ACPI Error: Methode parse/execution failed [\_TZ.TZ01._TMP] (Mode
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PC10.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD] Namespace lookup failure,
ACPI Error: Methode parse/execution failed [\_TZ.TZ01._TMP] (Mode   
ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 Serr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen t4
ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
ata2: SError: { DevExch }
```

and It got stuck. Couldn't boot ubuntu.
So I installed Manjaro ( My friend gave me this KDE crash bundle ).
But apparantly I can atleast get to a GUI, I works just natuarally.

I replaced the Ubuntu with Manjaro but the error is still there.
Somewhere in askubuntu some guy with same problem had it fixed by connecting HDD to another computer.

I removed and connected the HDD to My Ubuntu PC,

Same problem.

So I removed it from system. 
Now my desktop's Ubuntu show the same problem after this. But I can boot into the GUI in it.

Removed Ubuntu, tried updating BIOS ( Installrd in MBR in BIOS )Not helpful.

Microsoft's Windows 10 isn't giving me any complaint. HDD is perfectly healthy.

This thing is slowing down the entire system.

Changing and going to tty , Can't log in as this message is FLOODING.
Even Live Disk booting shows same messages.

Please help me.

This thing isn't going away, It infected into My PC too ( Bcoz I connected it to PC)

My theory is its genarated some config file or something coz my laptop's sata cable was a little loose but now Its fixed but Linux isn't recognising it.

I tried many distros. No solutions so far. Googled it, No solution.

HELP ME PLZZZ.

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: Make sure your BIOS is up to date. This is most likely a BIOS version issue.

Comment: I had the same problem and it seems to be due issues with proprietary graphics drivers (i.e. NVIDIA drivers in my case). [This](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/) worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Just had a *similar* issue myself, try:

1. Hold down Left-Shift on boot to bring up the GRUB menu
2. Press `e` to edit the default boot parameters
3. At the end of the `kernel` line (near the bottom), add `acpi=off` - if you have other `acpi` options place this one before them
4. `F10` to boot

That should at least get you past the ACPI errors and booting, getting it working is another story entirely.

These steps work for disabling ACPI in Ubuntu 16.10 but still have no idea what is actually causing issues. For me this happened just after doing an update.

**Edit:**

Okay, so for me I found I could get away with just using `pci=noacpi` and everything I can remember working before is working again (with exception to my GPU). I then set these changes permanently in GRUB: [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

My guess is that either my BIOS is genuinely corrupted (after doing nothing to it), or that ACPI was changed in the update and the reboot caused these non-working updates to be used in my system.

**Edit of Edit:**

I found that `acpi=strict` allows booting and for my GTX 960M graphics card to be picked up. I think it had something to do with it sending an interrupt that would allow the kernel to know it's there or something.

Comment: I will try them but I'm currently away from my Laptop. Will update soon. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: No problem, also add to your post the output of `uname -r` and `lshw` (once you get booted).