# Blackscreen after GRUB screen right after upgrading Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, upgrade

I have a problem with my installation of Ubuntu. I installed it fresh using a live USB stick to another USB stick with `fast boot` and `secure boot` disabled.

I'm using an Asus Zenbook UX562F with an integrated GTX 1050 Max-Q.
After the installation, I installed Nvidia-390 and updated the kernel with ukuu to 4.20.17 to fix no sound issue.

After the reboot, everything went well and I did:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade + J
```

All was done well, so I restarted and on the next boot after selecting Ubuntu in GRUB it gave me a long black screen (violet screen) where nothing changes after so much time.

I tried to add `nomodeset` and `noveau.modeset=0` single and together but didn't help so I don't know what to do.

**Edit:**

I had a random lucky boot but was not able to repeat it. (Just to add this Information.)

Trying the solutions on [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/) didn't work for me.

I tried purging nvidia and install old driver nvidia-375 but still no boot.

I also installed Ubuntu on my internal SSD where I ran into the same issue:
-booting after installation - works
-booting after upgrading the kernel to 5.1.4 - works
-booting after dist-upgrade - get stuck after grub

Lucky boots were reproducable but rare so TTY solutions are possible to apply

Starting with `nomodeset` and `noveaus.modeset=0` is also not possible what makes me think it's not an nvidia issue

**Edit:**

When I got a lucky boot some error messages I have taken a picture of them:

[image: Boot messages]

Comment: found no solution in the link :/ but thx for the idea

Comment: [This might help](https://askubuntu.com/a/962099/816190)

Comment: thx kulfy using acpi=off let the error messages disappear when i got a booting system but also disables my touchpad it didn't solve my booting problem

Comment: WinEu* said this already. I tried the solutions but didn't help me