# Installing Ubuntu 19.04 in HP Omen 15, RTX 2070 Max Q, 32GB RAM, 12 cores

Tags: boot, 19.04, acpi

I am trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop. I recently brought this laptop, and I am getting 2-3 types of errors when installing Ubuntu.

[image: Screenshot of error]

I am installing it with Windows 10. I am installing via USB (San Disk). I am getting `ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE....`, after clicking on *Install Ubuntu* in the boot menu.

Last time I got an error like `acpi bios error (bug) could not resolve [\_SB.PC10.12C2.TPDOJ], A`... but the error changed automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: no, my problem is different. Sir @Pilot6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACPI Errors when booting , Can't boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953666/acpi-errors-when-booting-cant-boot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try booting with the options `libata.noacpi=1` or `acpi=off`. Here on [Turn Off ACPI while Booting Ubuntu via Grub2 - Ubuntu Sharing](http://ubuntuguide.net/turn-off-acpi-ubuntu-grub2), you can find how to do that.

Sources:

- [Turn Off ACPI while Booting Ubuntu via Grub2 - Ubuntu Sharing](http://ubuntuguide.net/turn-off-acpi-ubuntu-grub2)
- [ACPI Error: Una tontería de GNU/Linux que me ha vuelto loco | Quijote Libre](https://quijotelibre.com/2017/10/12/acpi-error-una-tonteria-de-gnulinux-que-me-ha-vuelto-loco)

Comment: But ACPI is important, right?

Comment: Yes, but maybe you won't have the same issue after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu. But on startup, It does not show the option to load Ubuntu. In order to load Ubuntu, I need to plug in USB, boot it, but this time quit the installation, and then Ubuntu starts.

Comment: Why this problem really? I have a clean new laptop, worth 2500$....I am really pissed. I got a project of 500$ before 2 days, but I failed to do it because of this Ubuntu bug.

Comment: Since no one answered, I am marking your answer as best. At least you answered.  But I am still looking for a permanent and good solution.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

Try kernel bootparameter:  **pci=nommconf**

**Full version:**

I had the same very nasty problem with ACPI,
On boot the kernel basically spamming:

```
kernel: [ 26.237796] ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE 08,
```

Kernel bootparameter: acpi=off made the sytem bootable, but the laptop basically unusable (no touchpad, no cpu throttling, nvidia could not initialize etc etc.)

After much agony I found that it was described here very recently (hopefully pached soon):   https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203617

Which suggested using: **pci=nommconf**

which solved my problem for now.  I have so far not found any serious drawback so Im happy.