# HP Omen ubuntu setup problem ACPI Error: no handler or method for GPE (number), disabling event (code)

Tags: 18.04, hp, acpi, nouveau, nomodeset

I have laptop HP Omen 15-dh0004ur

Several days I've been trying to setup Linux distribution, and its failed. Problem with Ubuntu installation, photo of the screen attached.
Also I've checked different Linux distributions, the same results (sometimes with different errors)
On the laptop, I have installed Windows 10 by default.

I've tryed to use option `nouveau.setmode=0` after `---` in GRUB (edit mode).
Also `nomodeset` option, it doesn't help with installation.

`nouveau.setmode=0` option

[image: nouveau.setmode=0 option]

Once by some miracle Ubuntu distribution have done the setup, without any errors, but after reloading I haven't seen anything in boot options (UEFI)

I followed instruction of this [tutorial](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-To-Install-Ubuntu-16-04-with-NVIDIA-Drivers-and-CUDA-1097/) by Ubuntu server installation and faced with same problems.

errors (photos) :

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1168437/1010300 You can try my suggestion (TLDR: kernel param: pci=nommconf) and see if it works for you.
It solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version.
While booting using the live USB, remember to enter the try ubuntu before installing option by pressing E at the selection window and then typing `acpi=off` before the words in the script on your screen `quiet splash`.
Later install ubuntu pressing the icon that appears on the trial desktop.