# Kernel ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, mac, acpi

I'm booting Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB Stick on my MacBook Pro 2018. When I chose either Try Ubuntu without installing or Install Ubuntu, I get the following error code and the Kernel panics:

```
ACPI Exception: AE_NO_MEMORY, SSDT 0xFFFF9E606B75CC00 Table is duplicated (20170831/tbdata-562)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU0.GCAP, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU0._PDC, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Exception: AE_NO_MEMORY, SSDT 0xFFFF9E606BBDF800 Table is duplicated (20170831/tbdata-562)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU1.APPT, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU1.GCAP, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU1._PDC, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Exception: AE_NO_MEMORY, SSDT 0xFFFF9E606B57A400 Table is duplicated (20170831/tbdata-562)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU1.APCT, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU1.GCAP, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU1._PDC, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 34
BUG: stack guard page was hit at (ptrual (stack is (ptural).. (ptural))
kernel stack overflow (page fault): 0000 [#1] SMP PT1
Modules linked in:
...
...
...
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attepted to kill init! exit code=0x0000000b

Kernel Offset: 0x29e00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xfffffffff80000000-0xfffffffffbfffffff)
-- [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
```

where the `...` contains some more info that I believe is not helpful.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

I have already tried setting `acpi=off` as suggested at [ACPI Errors when booting , Can't boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953666/acpi-errors-when-booting-cant-boot)
When I did, I just got a black screen for hours.

Edit: the same stick on a different non-mac laptop works.

Comment: I would suggest verifying your ISO download https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and especially write to install media https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  *It may not be your problem, but eliminating it can save-days hours of later diagnosis that will be wasted if either was flawed*

Comment: Do you have a nvidia card?

Comment: I have Radeon Pro 560X 4096 MB and
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Comment: Have you tried booting with the `nomodeset` option?