# Won't boot after 22.04 upgrade, acpi errors, Razer stealth 2020

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, nvidia-geforce, ultrabook

laptop specs: GTX 1650 Ti Max-Q,Core i7-1065G7

After being prompted to, I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04. After completing, system was restarted and then it will not boot after selecting Ubuntu in the grub menu.

Screenshots of errors attached, some with acpi and i915 requests. You can also see I have a few boot params added like intremap because of boot and graphics issues I had with the previous version. But now it won't boot with it without them.
Any ideas? Thanks

[image: boot parmas]

[image: black screen error 1]

[image: black screen error 2]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was going to just try clean installing debian based Deepin. But first I tried things mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953666/acpi-errors-when-booting-cant-boot). acpi=strict still didn't allow booting. acpi=off did allow me to login to Ubuntu, but system performance was really bad, almost unusable, and trackpad didn't work. It was enough to allow me to install a bunch of auto updates, one of which I remember was Nvidia related. Then after 2 reboots (1st time it was still messed up somehow) everything is working well, startup even seems faster now. Not really sure what was the exact "fix" lol. Also, I still keep the same grub boot params I had before: "intremap=off quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open $vt_handoff"